# Simple - getting record id instead of desired attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a really simple question but I am new. I am trying to create a dropdown menu with values populated from the model. However, instead of displaying the city names, I am getting the record id's like: 0x007fee0b7442c0 (not sure if these are called id's, I think there is another term).

Controller:

```
@cities = City.find(:all, select: "name")
```

View:

```
<%= f.select(:city, @cities) %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the `name` attribute from the database then do:

```
@cities = City.pluck(:name)
# => ["Sydney", "Melbourne", "Canberra"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: [select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)

```
@cities = City.select(:name)
<%= f.select(:city, @cities.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.name ] }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide to using collection_select here

http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/rails/using-collection_select-in-rails/

Answer (score 0):

You can also improve on `@cities = City.find(:all, select: "name")` by instead doing

```
@cities = City.pluck(:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display city name in the select box, and you want to pass the city id as a parameter on form submit, use this

```
f.select :city, @cities.map {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
```